# Android creating a circle bitmap without drawing it on canvas

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, geometry

My question is: is there any way to create a circle and then make it bitmap and not to display it on canvas??For example make a black circle then convert it to a bitmap but not using the  canvas.setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap).Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily get a bitmap object using [Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap) static method (Bitmap.create) and then use that object to draw anything on it by instantiating a [canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) object with `bitmapObject`.

your code should look something like this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.create(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
//draw on your canvas.
```

Comment: :/ yes i know this method but i dont need to draw it on screen this is my prob :/

Comment: sorry :/ i am newbie to programming i am not even a programmer.Sorry again.And thank you bro